# Auto-create BQ tables for streaming inserts

Tags: python, google-bigquery

Maybe I got this wrong: Is there a way to automatically create the target table for a tabledata.insertAll command? If yes please point me in the right direction.

If not - what is the best approach to create the tables needed? Check for existing tables on startup and create the ones that does not exist by loading from GCS? Or can they be created directly from code without a load job?

I have a number of event classes (Python Cloud endpoints) defined and the perfect solution would be using those definitions to create matching BQ tables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to create a table automatically during streaming, since BigQuery doesn't know the schema. JSON data that you post doesn't have type information -- if there is a field "123" we don't know if that will always be a string or whether it should actually be an integer. Additionally, if you post data that is missing an optional field, the schema that got created would be narrower than the one you wanted.

The best way to create the table is with a tables.insert() call (no need to run a load job to load data from GCS). You can provide exactly the schema you want, and once the table has been created you can stream data to it.

In some cases, customers pre-create a month worth of tables, so they only have to worry about it every 30 days. In other cases, you might want to check on startup to see if the table exists, and if not, create it.

Comment: Thx. I ended up checking what tables exist (tables.list) on application start and then creating the missing ones by doing a query selecting zeroed data into a new table (insert)

Comment: That works too. If you don't want to insert blank rows, you can do something like: `SELECT * from (SELECT 0 as foo, "" as bar) WHERE false`, which will create an empty result but with a schema.

Comment: @JordanTigani also, is there a grace time after a table is created? I found we are missing data rightly after creating a table in our stream process and the API is not giving us any exceptions or errors.

Comment: There is a 'warm up' time of approximately 5 minutes between when data is first streamed to a table and when it is available to query. This warm up time also applies when you stop streaming to a table for more than 24 hours and then start again. We're working on reducing the warm up time.